# Is there a limit on how many wall posts(from the past) can I get of a Facebook page using the Graph API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I would think there would be a cut-off on the number of posts, or a cut-off in time period after which I won't be able to get the posts. From a few test runs, I am unable to form any idea as for some pages it returns all the posts till the beginning whereas for some it stops midway. Also neither is the number of posts hinting towards a constant limit, nor is the first post time hinting at any time cut-off.
The documentation(http://developers.facebook.com/d...) doesn't talk about any limit, so I am out of ideas. Can anyone throw some light on this and provide some credible information? Thanks already for your time.

Comment: I'm having the same issue actually.  It seems you can only go back a month or so.  After that all calls return nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/ was updated to show you get up to 25 posts.

Comment: Thanks for the update. But I was looking for the limit when it comes to posts from a Page's Wall, and not User's.

Comment: Got it, this is a pages question. The limit should be the same as that of a user, up to 25.